# Shooting a projectile but goes in wrong direction - 2D game

Tags: c#, game-physics, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a simple game where I am shooting a projectile when the user touches the screen, I first spawn 8 projectiles (sprites) and when the user touches the screen I would like the top projectile to fly in the touch direction. I was able to do this; However, every time I shoot, the projectile goes in the wrong direction, here is an image which will illustrate the issue.

[image: Projectile]

Obviously the image is still here but the object will continue flying until it goes out of the screen and then gets destroyed.

Here is the code snippet that handles this

**GameplayController.cs**

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0);
        position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position);

        GameObject target;
        target = new GameObject();
        target.transform.position = position;


        Arrow comp = currentArrows[0].GetComponent<Arrow>();
        comp.setTarget(target.transform);
        comp.GetComponent<Arrow>().arrowSpeed = 12;
        comp.GetComponent<Arrow>().shoot = true;
        currentArrows.RemoveAt(0);
        Destroy(target);
    }
```

I know I am getting the mouse input here and not the phone touch and that's fine for me, later I will convert it to the touch input.

**Arrow.cs**

```
public bool shoot = false;
public float arrowSpeed = 0.0f;
public Vector3 myDir;
public float speed = 30.0f;
private Transform target;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(shoot)
    {
        transform.position += transform.right * arrowSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

}


public void setTarget(Transform targetTransform)
{
    this.target = targetTransform;
    Vector3 vectorToTarget = target.position - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(vectorToTarget.y, vectorToTarget.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    Quaternion q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, q, Time.deltaTime * speed);
}

private void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    print("Disappeared");
    Destroy(gameObject);
    Gameplay.instance.isShooting = false;
}
```

Comment: why do you use this?
` transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, q, Time.deltaTime * speed);`

Comment: @HieuNguyenTrung Already got rid of that and now I am using Lerp instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Vector3 position = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0);

I think that your problem is that you're getting the *screen* coordinates by click, not the world coordinates, which is actually two different things. In order to direct your projectile correctly you need to convert your screen coordinates to world like it's done [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/540888/converting-mouse-position-to-world-stationary-came.html).

The next thing is how you move the projectile:

```
transform.position += transform.right * arrowSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```

You're moving the projectile to the right and then rotating it somehow. Maybe you should try to move it with [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html), which will be easier and rotate it with [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html).

Comment: Done that and its the same issue... I updated the code, and included that line of code.

Comment: @MuhandJumah, edited the answer. I looked at projectile movement code once more. Try to change the way you move the projectile to Vector3.Lerp, this will be simplier

Comment: @That worked but it would translate the object to the mouse coordinates, what about if I want the object to keep flying as long as there is no collision? I am handling the destruction of the object when it moves out of the camera. I want it to keep flying in the direction of the mouse click.

Comment: @MuhandJumah - rotate the object so that it looks in the direction (Transform.LookAt) once at the beginning of the launch and then try using Transform.Translate in the Transform.Forward direction (of course multiplying it by the speed and all needed deltas)

Comment: thanks again, I was able to get it to fly in the direction using this line of code in Update var forward = Vector3.forward;
        
            //transform.position += transform.right * arrowSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            transform.Translate(forward * 30 * Time.deltaTime); and transform.LookAt(target, Vector3.forward); in my launching. 1 issue though Z keeps changing and the bullet disappears from view when it reaches mouse coordinates. I tried setting forward.z to 0 but that doesn't help at all. any ideas? And thank you so much, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @MuhandJumah why you're using Vector3.forward (- it's (0,0,1) which can affect your z ) as 2nd param in LookAt? According to the docs it stands for Vector specifying the upward direction. So try leave it empty or use Vector3.up.

Comment: I tried LookAt(target) and then in update transform.Translate(transform.forward * 30 * Time.detaTime) and I still get the same behavior, the projectile would disappear at the mouse coordinates (the z changes) even adding Vector3.up causes the same issue. But I was able to solve it by creating a temp vector and set it equal to transform.forward then setting its z to 0. that helped solve the problem. But if you have any better solution I would love to know it. Thank you once more.